# Как перебрать строки спарсенные из excel pandas'ом?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, selenium

Есть код, где я тестирую сайт, а именно строку валидации имени, все имена у меня записаны в excel.
Я спарсил excel через pandas, но не пойму как обращаться построчно.
Обновил: написал for, а в него поместил функцию в которую передаются значения, но тесты валятся после первого с указанием на последнюю строку ошибка True

```
import unittest
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

URL = 'https://psy.edu.ru/'

class check_psyedu(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Алексей\YandexDisk\Job\Python\Test\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')
    
    i = 0
    df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\\Users\\Алексей\\YandexDisk\\Job\\Python\\Test\\list_name.xlsx')
    for row in df.itertuples():
        def test_box_name(self):
            #df.loc[0]
            driver = self.driver
            driver.implicitly_wait(3)
            driver.maximize_window()
            driver.get(URL)
            name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/input')
            button= driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/section[6]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div/div[4]/div[1]/button')
            name.send_keys(df.loc[{i}])
            button.click()
    i += 1

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое:

```
    for row in df.iterrows():
        #row - строка со значениями
```